# These two code blocks in C look very similar, but have different effects. What causes the difference?

Tags: c

This block has no effect on the result at all, even though I set the values to zero:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < net.n ; ++i){
    layer l = net.layers[i];
    if(l.type == CONVOLUTIONAL){
        //save_convolutional_weights(l, fp);
        l.weights_quant_multipler = 0;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the values are set to zero, which dramatically changes the result:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < net.n; ++i) {
    layer *l = &net.layers[i];

    if (l->type == CONVOLUTIONAL) {

        l->weights_quant_multipler = 0;
    }
}
```

What causes the difference? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, in one version you make a copy of `net.layers[i]` while in the other you access the original element of the array. You might revisit your C text book about what pointers are and how they are used.

Comment: Sure, I'm more of a python person though

Answer (score 6):

The first code block make a copy of `net.layers[i]` and changes that. The second changes the original `net.layers[i]` through a pointer.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `l` is a different instance of `layer` than `net.layers[i]` - any changes made to `l` do not affect `net.layers[i]` (any more than changes to `net.layers[i+1]` affect `net.layers[i]`.

In the second case, `l` is a *pointer* to `net.layers[i]` - instead of being a separate instance of `layer`, it's a reference to `net.layers[i]`).

Writing `l->weights_quant_multiplier = 0` is exactly equivalent to writing `net.layers[i].weight_quant_multiplier = 0`.

```
 l == &net.layers[i] // layer * == layer *
*l ==  net.layers[i] // layer   == layer
```